# Umbraco GetCropUrl

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to set the selected crom for my image, But I'm stuck and cant figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

**ImageWithTextHover.cs**

```
public class ImageWithTextHover
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public Link Url { get; private set; }
    public MediaItem Image { get; private set; }
    public string Crop { get; private set; }


    public ImageWithTextHover(IPublishedContent content)
    {
        Text = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("text");
        Url = content.GetPropertyValue<MultiUrls>("link").FirstOrDefault();
        Crop = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("imageCrop");
        Image = content.GetMediaItem("image", Crop);
    }
}
```

**cshtml**

```
@using Umbraco.Site.Extensions.Models.DocumentTypes.Grid
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{ 
    Layout = null;
    ImageWithTextHover imagehover = new ImageWithTextHover(Model.Content);

}

<div class="imageWithTextHover">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding: 0;">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="@imagehover.Image.Url" />
                <div class="text">
                    @Html.Raw(imagehover.Text)
                </div>
            </div>

            <img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.Content, imagehover.Image.Url, imagehover.Crop)" />

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

@imagehover.Crop is equal to

> 1:1 - Square

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're making this so hard on yourself. The easiest way to get a crop is to delete the cs part, use Razor and do this in your cshtml:

If you have set an Image Cropper with specific crops:

```
<img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.Content, "yourCropperAlias", "yourCropAlias")" />
```

If you just want a standard crop without the Image Cropper:

```
@if (Model.Content.HasValue("image"))
{
    <img src="@Url.GetCropUrl(Model.Content, propertyAlias: "yourCropperAlias", height: 300, width: 400)" />
}
```

There's a guide [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper) about crops, maybe it will help. Of course, that's assuming you're using Umbraco 7 and above, because if you're using for example Umbraco 6, well crops are a whole different story.